# Inserting text with many newlines with gnu sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed, terminal, gnu

I have a `mainfile.txt` that contains

```
 *
 * Some text
 *
```

Using the command

```
while read file; do gsed -i '1i'"$(cat mainfile.txt)" "$file";
```

I insert the text from mainfile.txt into the beginning of every `file` that matches some criteria. However, it seems like the different lines in mainfile.txt are causing trouble. The error says `` gsed: can't find label for jump to `o' ``. This error does not occur when mainfile.txt contains one line only. When trying to find a solution I only found out how to insert new lines in sed, which is not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` requires that each line to insert end in a backslash, except the last. If that's not the case for your file, it won't work.

`ed` is a better choice for **ed**iting files than the non-standard `sed -i`, though if you're restricting yourself to GNU `sed`/`gsed` instead of whatever the OS-provided system `sed` is, that's less of an issue.

With either command, the best solution to insert the contents of one file in another is to use the `r` command instead to **r**ead the contents of a file into the buffer after the addressed line (It acts more like `a` than `i` that way):

```
printf "%s\n" "0r mainfile.txt" w | ed -s "$file"
```

Unfortunately, `sed` doesn't take an address of 0 to mean "before the first line" like `ed` does so it's harder to use `r` here in it.

---

Of course, just prepending one file to another can easily be done without either command:

```
cat mainfile.txt "$file" > temp.txt && mv -f temp.txt "$file"
```

or using `sponge(1)` from the [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package:

```
cat mainfile.txt "$file" | sponge "$file"
```

Comment: Upvoted for the `cat`+`mv` but add a success test `&&` in between to make it `cat mainfile.txt "$file" > temp.txt && mv -f temp.txt "$file"` so you don't zap your input file by `mv`ing an empty file onto it if the `cat` failed (e.g. if `temp.txt` isn't writable or `mainfile.txt` isn't readable).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The printf [...] | ed -s "$file" solution does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1ecat mainfile.txt' "$file"
```

On first line only of the file `$file`, evaluate the command `cat mainfile.txt`, then print all lines as normal.

`$file` will be updated with the lines of `mainfile.txt` prepended.

Alternative if the `$file` has at least 2 lines:

```
sed -i -e '1h;1r mainfile.txt' -e '1d;2H;2g' "$file"
```